# Visual Studio Professional 2013 - Issue publishing to IIS6

Tags: deployment, visual-studio-2013, publish

I have just upgraded from VS Express addition to VS Pro 2013.  With VS Express I have been publishing to a Win 2003 Server (IIS6) site without any issues.  Frontpage extensions etc are loaded.  Whenever I hit 'Publish Now' it would prompt for user credentials and worked well.

Now with VS Pro 2013 it says 'Failed to connect... The Web server  could not be found.'.  The server is fine and has not changed, I can load the previously published version of my project in IE. All projects how have this problem. Nothing has changed on the server side.

Would anyone have an idea where I can look to fix this?  Please let me know if you need any more information.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know it's old but maybe this will help

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/vstudio/en-US/8279f108-37b1-4e97-8ef0-bda64cc8455a/visual-studio-2013-breaks-iis-configuration

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is best to provide the meat of the answer from the linked page here in your answer.  Links can change, content be removed, etc.